# Changing orientation of a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table which looks as follows:

```
count  occupation  gender
800    engineer     M
400    engineer     F
700    doctor       M
100    doctor       F
```

I want the table to look as

```
 Gender  engineer doctor
   M     800      700
   F     400      100
```

How can I bring about this change?

Comment: ***WHAT database?!?*** SQL is just the query language - that doesn't really tell us what you're using. Things like this are often vendor-specific, so the ISO/ANSI-Standard-SQL will often not be sufficient to handle this. What database are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? DB2? Please update your tags accordingly!

Comment: This is a matter of presentation. Handle this logic in your application. Not in the DB. Use the DB only to get raw data.

Comment: ok, so is there anyway I can get this change in presentation?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      [count] INT
    , occupation VARCHAR(20)
    , gender CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @temp ([count], occupation, gender)
VALUES 
    (800, 'engineer', 'M'),
    (400, 'engineer', 'F'),
    (700, 'doctor', 'M'),
    (100, 'doctor', 'F')

SELECT *
FROM @temp
PIVOT 
(
    SUM([count]) 
    FOR occupation IN ([engineer], [doctor])
) p
ORDER BY gender DESC
```

**Output:**

```
gender engineer    doctor
------ ----------- -----------
M      800         700
F      400         100
```

**Update #2:**

**Query:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      [count] INT
    , occupation VARCHAR(20)
    , gender CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #temp ([count], occupation, gender)
VALUES 
    (800, 'engineer', 'M'),
    (400, 'engineer', 'F'),
    (700, 'doctor', 'M'),
    (100, 'doctor', 'F'),
    (100, 'tester', 'F'),
    (100, 'programmer', 'M'),
    (100, 'programmer', 'F'),
    (100, 'programmer', 'M')

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ', [' + occupation + ']'
    FROM #temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '
    SELECT *
    FROM #temp
    PIVOT 
    (
        SUM([count]) 
        FOR occupation IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) p
    ORDER BY gender DESC'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
gender doctor      engineer    programmer  tester
------ ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
M      700         800         200         NULL
F      100         400         100         100
```

Comment: But what do I do if there are say 10 professions instead of just doctor,engineer?